# BroadcastReceiver that working even when the app is closed

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.1-oreo

I have a question about BroadcastReceivers. I have an app that needs to receive constantly the ACTION_TIME_TICK intent to refresh the clock widgets. I implemented a foreground service which contains a BroadcastReceiver that listens to that action. But on android oreo the only way to start a service is starting it as foreground service which implies to show a persistent notification to the user which notify that the app is working in background.
I don't want to show to the user that notification. I tried to implement BroadcastReceiver inside the Application class. But this is not working proprely. Somethimes the BroadcastReceiver doesn't work and somethimes works well. Even when it works well, if the app is removed from the recent tasks, the BroadcastReceiver stops to work. Is there a way to use a BroadcastReceiver that works indefinitely without the use of a service?

Comment: whats wrong with a `TextClock` in the widget?

Comment: You cannot use a custom typeface with text clock. And my widgets are little bit complicated

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use a BroadcastReceiver that works indefinitely without the use of a service?

In the case of `ACTION_TIME_TICK`: No, since you cannot use a manifest-declared BroadcastReceiver.

Since you're not willing to use a foreground service, you may want to look into [`START_STICKY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY). In this situation, that's the only way to maximize your Service's run-time: Allow the system to re-start it, capriciously, after it's been stopped for lack of resources. Of course, this means your clock could stop updating for arbitrarily long periods of time.

Note that your problem is not limited to Oreo (Oreo does not require you to be a foreground service, but it does impose certain limits on what you're allowed to do if you're NOT in the foreground). Even on earlier OSs, if you're not foreground, the system considers you a prime candidate for elimination.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I already used START_STICKY, but this doesn't help for restarting the service when killed. I'm using a repeating alarmManager with an interval of 2 minutes that starts the service again even if it's not killed. But the alarmManager doesn't work too. Some devices need to turn off battery optimization to let the service work. But it's not a good approach. An average user doesn't know how to turn off the battery optimization, he simply want the app that works as expected.

Comment: Actually, if you get into the weeds on START_STICKY, it is supposed to restart the service when it's killed -- when the OS feels like it. I've never seen it work, personally, but others have. I think the moral of the story is, "you can't do what you're trying to do", at least not on stock Android.